# Google chart formatting

Tags: jquery, javascript, google-visualization

I have the following script which I need to modify a little.  Here is the json:

```
[
    {"User1":{"v": 50.00,"f": "£100"}},
    {"User2":{"v": 10.00,"f": "£20"}},
    {"User3":{"v": 10.00,"f": "£20"}},
    {"User4":{"v": 10.00,"f": "£20"}},
    {"User5":{"v": 20.00,"f": "£40"}}
]
```

and here is the script:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAjax);

    function drawChartAjax() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'chart_json.aspx', 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(data) { 
                drawChart(data); 
            } 
        });
    }

    function drawChart(json) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'User');
        data.addColumn('number', 'v');
        data.addRows(json.length);
        for(var j in json) {
            for(var k in json[j]) {
                data.setValue(parseInt(j), 0, k);
                data.setValue(parseInt(j), 1, json[j][k].v);
            }
        }
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( document.getElementById('chart_div') );
        chart.draw(data, {width: 500, height: 300, is3D: true, title: 'Work In Progress'});
    }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works by giving me a nice piechart, How do I get the "f" value into the chart too from the JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an f column:

```
data.addColumn('number', 'v');
data.addColumn('number', 'f'); // <- new line
```

And, add the data to the rows:

```
for(var k in json[j]) {
    data.setValue(parseInt(j), 0, k);
    data.setValue(parseInt(j), 1, json[j][k].v);
    data.setValue(parseInt(j), 2, parseInt(json[j][k].f.substring(1))); // <- new line
}
```

But, I don't know how a pie chart handles that.

Comment: Ah - because the data is not numeric (because of the pound symbol). You can either make it numeric (server or client side), or change the data type for column f from 'number' to 'string'.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to insert that data keeping the 'number' data type. It just chops off the first character (the pound symbol) and then parses the string to an int.

Comment: That works almost perfectly!  But just need to display the "£" symbol too once the chart has been created.  Is that possible at all?

Comment: Looks like I don't need the percentage in the json data, the google chart is able to work out the percentage automatically based on the £ value!  But still need to display the £ symbol somehow.

Comment: The 'v' in `addColumn('number', 'v')` is the column name - so putting a pound symbol in there might help.

Comment: Figured it out. var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '£'});
formatter.format(data, 1);